# need to select atleast one checkbox using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using this javascript code. and on button click I want that atleast one checkbox selection is required. do anyone have idea what I am doing wrong. I don't want to use jquery.

```
function check()
{
var flag = false;
for(var i=1;i<=4;i++)
{
  var checkb = document.getElementById("check"+i);

  if(checkb.checked)
  {
    flag = true;
    break;
  }
}
if(!flag)
alert("What is your interest \n(select at least one option)");
return flag;
}
</script>
```

Button Click Code is

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return check();">
```

Comment: ... and how is it not working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine. Do hou have `id="check1"` set on your checkbox tags?

Comment: <input name="pref[]" type="checkbox"  id="file" value="Yes"  /> There are 4 checkbox and all have different ID, while in Firebug when I look.. its shows an error "checkb is null"

Comment: You're getting the elements by id in `document.getElementById("check"+i);` so you need `id="check1"` instead of `id="file"`.

Comment: thanks buddy..Initially its was working and I did same thing. but later on I really messed up totally.. Thanks Man for your great help.

Comment: Hi Secator, Is there any better coding style to write this code. I assume my code is not follow a good pattern?

Comment: Why you do not want to use jQuery?

Comment: you are right its so easy to code in jquery.. But I am making a form in joomla using Breezingforms. But for that I have to give a jquery library path in template and I can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code works fine as noted by the comments above. However, you could do your check for...checks a little more cleanly - you're expecting "check0" - "check4" for the IDs. You could just grab them all and not worry about a set limit (odds are your code isn't working because at least one of the IDs you're using doesn't exist).

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check0" />
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="check3" />
<hr/>
<input type="button" onclick="checkIt();" value="Check the Checks">
```

And some JS:

```
checkIt = function()
{
    var checks = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var hasCheck = false;  
    for(i in checks)
    {
        // Could also check for a classname here to narrow 
        // your result set.
        if(checks[i].type == 'checkbox')
            hasCheck |= checks[i].checked;
    }

    if(!hasCheck)
        alert('You should check one!');

    return hasCheck;
}
```